# Rails 5: render partial in another partial with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I'm a bit stuck in trying to implement AJAX where on "link_to" view is rendered and in that view I have another AJAX call.

I have menu sidebar where there is something like this:

```
<li class="<%= is_active_action('positions') %>"><%= link_to "Positions", positions_path, remote: true %></li>
```

In *application.html.erb* I have this:

```
<!-- Main view  -->
<div id="yield">
   <%= yield %>
</div>
```

Actually not sure if this is the right way to do, but so far it worked.

Then in *views/../positions/index.js.coffee* I have this

```
$("#yield").empty()
  .append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'inventory/positions/index') %>")
```

which is redering /positions/_index.html.erb partial. In there I have `<div id="media_list">` and `<div id='positions_table'>`

In assets/javascripts I have *positions.coffee*

```
$ ->
$(document).on 'change', '#media_list', (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'update_positions',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        media_id: $("#media_list option:selected").val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("Dynamic media select OK!")
```

This is basically listening to drop-down change and then passing `media_id` to controller, then this */views/../positions/update_positions.js.coffee* renders second partial (/views/../positions/_positions.html.erb):

```
$("#positions_table").empty()
  .append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'inventory/positions/positions', locals: {positions: @positions}) %>")
```

**At the moment on dropdown change I cannot make second partial (_positions.html.erb) to render.** Any ideas what could be wrong? Thank you for any help.

**Update**

I've set in my routes this:
`get '/update_positions', to: 'inventory/positions#update_positions'`
and then in controller I have this:

```
def update_positions
  @positions = Positions::Positions.where('media_id = ?', params[:media_id])
```

When `:media_id` is passed, I get this in console `Started GET "/update_positions?media_id=1"` and result visually is as expected. But then when I do several similar requests in a row, strange things happen. It looks like requests ar multiplying and seems that there are much historic requests repeating again and again. My assumption is that is because of this `/update_positions?media_id=1` Please, help, what am I doing wrong?

**Update 2**

First of all I adjusted route to actual Controller I have: 
`get '/inventory/positions/update_positions', to: 'inventory/positions#update_positions'` 
Previous route did not work correctly when I jumped from routes like `/users/1/edit`.

In my */views/inventory/positions/update_positions.js.coffee* I have this:

```
$("#positions_table").empty()
  .append('<%=j render 'inventory/positions/positions'%>');
```

Multiple queries look like this:

```
Started GET "/inventory/positions/update_positions?media_id=1" for 78.84.173.112 at 2016-12-20 05:29:39 +0000
  Parameters: {"media_id"=>"1"}  
  #several queries follow
Started GET "/inventory/positions/update_positions?media_id=1" for 78.84.173.112 at 2016-12-20 05:29:39 +0000
  Parameters: {"media_id"=>"1"}
  #several queries follow
```

This happens when I open particular view, select let' say "value: 1" from dropdown and particular partial is rendered. Then I go to another AJAX view in different section, then come back and again select "value: 1". If I do it multiple times, then queries happen to copy more and more. It stops, when I do full page refresh - then everything starts from normal position, but again queries grow, when I repeat select multiple times.

Comment: In your console, is it showing "Dynamic media select OK!" when you make the dropdown change or "AJAX Error: ..."?

Comment: @luckyruby No, it seems that listener is not working at all - nothing in console. `update_positions

Comment: `update_positions

Comment: I'm sorry - `update_positions` is controller action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *application.html.erb*:

```
<!-- Main view  -->
<div id="yield">
  <div id="positions_index"></div>
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

In *positions/index.js.coffee*:

```
$("#positions_index").html "<%= escape_javascript(render 'inventory/positions/index') %>"
$("#positions_index").on "change", "#media_list", (e) ->      
  $.get '/update_positions',
    media_id: $("#media_list option:selected").val()
  , null
```

Make sure you have update_positions defined in your routes.

Comment: Thanks, works like charm! My naive idea was to use <% yield %> in order to render all dynamic stuff in my app, so my nav bars do not refresh. Do you think there is any option to avoid a lot of `<div id=...>` in future in application.html.erb?

Comment: Silly me :) I'll just use <div id="yield"> in every page and that's it. So basically when I load different section of my app, I'll refer to id="yield".

Comment: Please, can you check my update above, as I have got some strange thinks in console when implemented your `positions/index.js.coffee` suggestion. Visually I get the desired result, however "behinf the scenes" there are a lot of unnecessary queries happening when same on change event is executed.

Comment: What do the unnecessary queries look like?

Comment: Please, see my **Update 2** above.

Comment: Use .html() instead of .empty().append(). Is #media_list inside of #positions_table?

Comment: #media_list is dropdown, which pass media_id param to render #positions_table and both are in single index view

Comment: Tried to use .html() instead of .empty().append however it did not help - same thing in console - queries keep accumulating